# Angular 2 Sending data to child

Tags: angular, undefined, subscribe, subject

Why I obtain undefined value of truck, when I send data from TransportComponent, to TruckComponent?

```
 export class TransportComponent {
 actualTransport: Subject<any> = new Subject();

 this.serviceTransport.subscribe( (data) => {   
            data.transports.forEach(transport => {
              this._truckService.getTruck(transport.idTransport)
                .subscribe((truck) => {
                  data.truck = truck ///Here I add to data field truck
                });
            });
          this.actualCourse.next(truck);
        });
 }
```

This is template of TransportComponent:

```
<tabset >
  <tab heading="Trucks">
    <truck [actualTransport]="actualTransport"></general>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Bus">
    <bus [actualTransport]="actualTransport"></general>
  </tab>
 </tabset>
```

TruckComponent looks like that:

```
   export class TruckComponent {

   @Input() actualTransport: Subject<any>;

   ngOnInit() {
    this.actualCourse.subscribe(
    (data) => {
        console.log(data) // in browser console truck value, is 
        present
        console.log(data.truck) // here is undefined
      }
    }
  }
```

In browser console, truck value is undefined, but in object data it have all field populated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a subject here, and not just use `@Input` with a variable?

Comment: @AJT_82   
 No, I just wonder why this is happening.

Comment: Okay, then I'd suggest you just use variables instead of Subject :)

Comment: @AJT_82 thx :), 
If you see there are 2 components, when I use Subject, it keep all modifications, from all components and give access under added data or modified data in this object.

Answer (score 0):

I believe problem lies there, that you are using the `OnInit` lifecycle hook in TruckComponent and since it is a child component, `ngOninit()` gets triggered when it's parent component TransportComponent initializes.
I suggest you to move `ngOninit()` to your parent component and use `TruckComponent`'s `actualCourse.subscribe` method in a constructor.
Hope it helps!